# How to bypass this old windows application's free disk space check?

Tags: windows, winapi

This windows application checks the available disk space when an attempt is made to enable a feature.

The error message can be translated into "You need 2145461018 more bytes to load this tileset.

Choosing other tilesets might even yield a message claiming that a negative amount of bytes is needed. This could indicate a buffer overflow. Notice the window title "Error space on disk".

I would like to disable that memory check using the simplest method possible, but I am willing to disassemble it despite having next to zero knowledge which winapi calls are using to check the free disk space. I am grateful for any hint!

I already tried the compatibility options on the shortcut properties, which didn't help.

The error can also be reproduced in a vm guest with windows.

PE Explorer shows this is a WIN32 GUI app with a subsystem version 3.10

[image: application screenshot from vm]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently creating a ramdisk was enough to fool the application. I used the tool ImDisk and mounted a 50MB disk on which I installed the application.

Comment: It's a common problem with modern disk drives that the multiplication of the various registers overflows the result and appears to be too small.